# How can I change the screen resolution of Slax?

Tags: xorg, resolution, livecd

[Slax](http://slax.org) uses X.org for managing its GUI.

However, when I boot Slax (specifically in a VM), the resolution gets capped at 1024x768.

How can I increase the resolution to more fully utilize the screen estate available on my display?

I have already attempted to follow the old advice from the following sources:

- http://old.slax.org/forum.php?action=view&parentID=25516
- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/mandriva-30/changing-screen-resolution-552768
- http://slaxlive.blogspot.com/2005/07/slax-linux-step-by-step-first-step.html

Comment: tried to add `slax` as a tag, but my reputation is not high enough yet hereon

Comment: Any reason to expect your hardware/driver combo is limiting this? Any lines in the Xorg log showing how it's choosing 1024x768?

Comment: @user4186 - I can run other distros in much higher resolution, and all are in VirtualBox, too

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're missing the video driver and X is defaulting to a generic video driver. For example, if your video card is an AMD, you need the `radeon` XF86 video drivers, and if you're running inside a virtual machine you need the `vmware` or `virtualbox` drivers. These drivers are part of X, and to put an example, in Debian they appear on the package manager as `xserver-xorg-video-radeon`, on Arch I think they're listed as `xf86-video-radeon`.

Comment: how can I include those in Slax?